# RecyclerView.Adapter items with different layoutparams

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm using `RecyclerView` to show elements of my data set. everything seems to work perfectly except I had two different types of items and I wish to change the Margin of each type to emphasize this slight difference.
to this end I used the viewtype of the adapter , however `getLayoutParams()` in `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)` seems to not give the correct params which I need to modify. recreating this param from scratch dynamically (with all the shadow and what not) seems unjustified.

here's my code:

```
private final static int TYPE1= 1;
private final static int TYPE2= 2;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(data_set.get(position).isType1()) {
        return TYPE1;
    }
    return TYPE2;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
    int margin = parent.getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.end_margin);
    if(viewType == TYPE1)
    {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            params.setMarginStart(margin);
        }else{
            params.setMargins(margin,0,0,0);
        }
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```

and heres my xml for item_layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/item_card"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/img_loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_contact_name"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

many thanks for any guidance provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some trial and error, I found a rather weird solution which most likely stems from that fact that I do not know the working of `RecyclerView`well.
at any rate I solved this problem by getting `parent.getParent()`'s `CardView.LayoutParams` and after modifications setting it to the view.

here's the modified code:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
    int endMargin = MyApplication.getSharedContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.chat_end_margin);
    int margin = MyApplication.getSharedContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.chat_margin);
    if(viewType == TYPE1)
    {
        ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup)parent.getParent();
        CardView.LayoutParams params = (CardView.LayoutParams) (parentView.getLayoutParams());
        params.setMargins(endMargin,margin,margin,margin);
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call parent.getLayoutParams(); you are getting the params from the recyclerview.

If you want the parameter to the LinearLayout inside your xml file give it an id, and retrieve it inside your code. So something like this:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.mylinearlayout);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) myLayout.getLayoutParams();

//do something with parameters

myLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: it seems the parent was the Linearlayout inside the cardview of the xml I posted. I thought parent is the recyclerview, yet seems like not for whatever reason. at any rate you are right in the sense that the solution was finding the right Layoutparams.